# Not able to assign var to $2 var from command line bash

Tags: bash

I have the bash script. I have to assign to second passed var other var, or upper-cased content of the same var. When I try to do sth like this:

```
x=${2^^}
$2=$x)
```

I got: `line 173: xxx=XXX: command not found` 
When I try this command : `set -- ${2^^}`

`$2` seems to be..empty. When I echo it, terminal shows empty line.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign to `$2` directly, yo need to use `set`. Copy the `$@` array to a named array, change its second element, and use `set` to assign the values back:

```sh
arr=("$@")
arr[1]=${arr[1]^^}
set -- "${arr[@]}"
printf '%s\n' "$2"
```

`set -- ${2^^}` sets the value of upper-cased `$2` to `$1` and clears the remaining positional arguments.

Comment: Is there a way to do this, without upper-casing first arg?

Comment: @TheTrainer: What? If I understand it correctly, upper-casing the first arg was the point?

Comment: second ;) But it works anyway - so I accepted your answer ;) I'm just curious  there's a that way.

Comment: Oh, in a named array, elements are numbered from 0, not 1, so the first element is in fact the second one :-)